# How to calculate coefficient of variation on cube or square root transformed data?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, coefficient-of-variation

I transformed data to be normal using a cube root transformation.  When I try to calculate the coefficient of variation I have tried back transforming the mean and sd (i.e., raise it to 3 "x^3") and then calculate the coefficient of variation, but this results in very small SDs relative to the mean.  Is there a more appropriate way to calculate the untransformed coefficient of variation here?

Comment: What is the obstacle to computing the CV directly with the original data?

Comment: So I need to use the mean and SD to calculate a trigger value, but I only do so if the CV is 0.5 or less.  If I am using a backtransformed mean and SD to calculate the trigger shouldn't I also calculate the CV on backtransformed data?